# Logging in Google App Script

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

im currently running a Telegram-Bot with App Script and I am trying to figure out how to log when people use a command in my bot. 
I want it to write down the time the name and a predefined text.

My idea was:

```
var time = new Date()
var name = "George"
if(text == "/ping"){
  var answer = "pong"
  sendText(id,answer); //Function sends the answer to the executer (working fine)
  Logger.log('%time - %name executed "/ping"', name, time)} //Not working
```

But it doesn't really work... I only get the information that i shall use the Logger API to create logs in my project. Looking forward to reading your answer :)

Comment: What is the textual error message that you get? How are you code is assigning a value to `text`?. Reference [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logger.log only works in the script editor. So a possible workaround would be to send yourself an email using [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) at a certain point in time.

Comment: I figured it out now. I used a Telegram Group with me and the bot. So now when someone uses a comment it sends a log message to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(String,Object...))

In summary: When writing to the log with `Logger.log()` you can use only `%s` as a format specifier for variables. e.g.

```
var my_var1 = "foo", my_var2 = 9876;
Logger.log("my_var1 = %s, my_var2 = %s", my_var1, my_var2); // logs: my_var1 = foo, my_var2 = 9876
```

alternatively, you could use plain string concatenation, rather than sprintf-style formatting:

```
var my_var1 = "foo", my_var2 = 9876;
Logger.log("my_var1 = " + my_var1 + ", my_var2 = " + my_var2); // also logs: my_var1 = foo, my_var2 = 9876
```

Comment: I still dont get a Log... Maybe the fact that i published it as a web application denys logs.

Comment: Yes, there's that, too.